# How to return a pointer to owned value that "does not live long enough"?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following code:

```
struct Node {
    id: uint
}

struct Graph {
    nodes: Vec<Node>
}

impl Graph {

    fn new() -> Graph {
        return Graph { nodes: Vec::new() };
    }

    fn create_node(&mut self) -> &Node {
        let index = self.nodes.len();
        let node = Node { id: index };
        self.nodes.push(node);
        // return &node;           // error: `node` does not live long enough
        return &self.nodes[index]; // ...but this work fine
    }

}
```

The idea is that the graph creates a new node and "lends" it to someone who calls the method. But I can not figure out how to return a reference to the newly created structure. The second return is working fine, but obviously not effective.

How to return a node without taking it back from the vector?

Comment: You say returning a reference to the `Vec` is "obviously not effective", but I don't understand *why* it's not effective.  Why don't you want to do that, and why can't you just return the `Node` by value?

Comment: @DK. I can't return `Node` by value because I previously pushed it into vector

Comment: As Vladimir says in his edit, just auto-derive a `Copy` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why you can't return `&node`:

```
fn create_node(&mut self) -> &Node {
    let index = self.nodes.len();
    let node = Node { id: index };
    println!("{}", &node as *const Node);
    self.nodes.push(node);
    println!("{}", &self.nodes[index] as *const Node);
    return &self.nodes[index];
}
```

Here's a sample output:

```
0x7fffc36a3418
0x7f4c96c2d000
```

As you can see, `&node` and `&self.nodes[index]` return completely different values. Moreover, `&node` (0x7fffc36a3418) will be invalid as soon as `create_node` returns, because this address points to `create_node` call frame, and a call frame is freed when a function returns.

Answer (score 2):

> But I can not figure out how to return a reference to the newly
>   created structure.

You can't. This is one of the basic errors which are ruled out by the ownership system.

Suppose you could. Then when your function returns such reference will point to destroyed memory.

You can read more on ownership in the [official guide on ownership](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ownership.html). It explains how ownership and borrowing work, including why your program is incorrect.

BTW, unless you have `#[derive(Copy)]` on your `Node`, taking a reference to `node` won't work also because `node` is moved into the vector. Ownership guide explains move semantics as well.

Comment: In my case, `node` lives as long as the `Graph`. Can I return a pointer to the value with the same lifetime as `&self`?

Comment: No, you can't, unless this value already has the same lifetime as `self`. That's why it's ok to return a reference into a vector (I don't really understand why you don't want to do it), but not ok to return a reference to a local variable. This really is a fundamental thing - it is not correct to say that `node` lives as long as `Graph` because it *does not*. It lives only for the duration of the function call and you can't change this fact without moving this value somewhere else (e.g. into `self`) - but then the original `node` will be unavailable because it is moved, ...

Comment: ... so you need to take a reference to the *new* place, not the old one.