# Returning a reference does not live long enough

Tags: mysql, rust, rust-cargo

I've just started learning Rust, and have come from a mainly JavaScript background so I'm a bit stumped when it comes to the whole borrowing system and memory management.

I have the following code:

```
fn load(db: &MyPool, id: i32) -> &Account{
    let accounts: Vec<Account> = db.prepare("SELECT id, balance, name FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`=?")
    .and_then(|mut stmt| {
        stmt.execute(&[&id]).map(|result| {
            result.map(|x| x.unwrap()).map(|row| {
                Account{
                    id: from_value(&row[0]), 
                    balance: from_value(&row[1]), 
                    name: from_value(&row[2])
                }
            }).collect()
        })
    }).unwrap();

    &accounts[0]

}
```

And I've managed to fix all the errors the compiler throws out apart from
`/main.rs:42:4: 42:12 error: 'accounts' does not live long enough`

Is this the best way to get one result from the MySQL query, or have I been going at it completely wrong?

Comment: Did you look at the [**37** other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+%22does+not+live+long+enough%22) that mention *"does not live long enough"*? How does this question differ from them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a pointer to owned value that "does not live long enough"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841657/how-to-return-a-pointer-to-owned-value-that-does-not-live-long-enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to return a reference to an account, but you want to *pass ownership* to the caller after retrieving from the db.

Thus, change the signature to:

```
fn load(db: &MyPool, id: i32) -> Account
```

Now the idea would be to return the object by value, not by reference:

```
accounts[0]
```

However doing so will fail with an `error: cannot move out of indexed content`. A better approach would be to avoid collecting in a vector altogether, and use [`Iterator::next(&self)`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) to take the first element. This would look like:

```
fn load(db: &MyPool, id: i32) -> Account{
    let account: Account = db.prepare("SELECT id, balance, name FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`=?")
    .and_then(|mut stmt| {
        stmt.execute(&[&id]).map(|result| {
            result.map(|x| x.unwrap()).map(|row| {
                Account{
                    id: from_value(&row[0]), 
                    balance: from_value(&row[1]), 
                    name: from_value(&row[2])
                }
            }).next().unwrap() // <- next() takes the first elt of the iterator
        })
    }).unwrap();

    account // <- return by value, pass ownership to caller
}
```

(Untested as I couldn't reproduce your dev environment.)

Kind of unrelated, but it is worth noting that those multiple `unwrap()` calls render your function extremely brittle as any failure will crash your whole program with a panic. Fortunately the answer to this bad smell is easy: you want to return `Option<Account>` rather than `Account`. Then remove all calls to `unwrap()` and let the `Option<Account>` propagate throughout calls (your use of `map()` is good because it says "return `None` if you find `None` and return `Some(f(a))` if you find `Some(a)`".)

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped a lot. Is there any other material you'd recommend me reading apart from the docs on the website?